# Angularjs $locationChangeStart for ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way that we can watch for location change with ui-router, the same way we can do it with $locationChangeStart (ngRoute). I've tried with $stateChangeStart event but it returns nothing.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function($event, next, current) { 

    console.log($event);
    console.log(next);
    console.log(current);

});
```

I can see **$locationChangeStart** events in **$rootScope** but not for **$stateChangeStart**. And logging detail returns different values for both these events.

I want to add watcher for multiple events like login watch etc...

Comment: Which version of UI-Router? V0.X or V1.X. With V1.X state change events have been replaced with transitions.

Comment: version is v1.0.20. Would you mind to explain more about transitions.

Comment: With UI-Router 1.X, state change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks. Instead of listening for events, use the Transition Hook API. 

For more information, see [UI-Router Guide - 1.0 Migration - State Change Events](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)